# How to store Web Service result in Array?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I am using KSoap to fetch .net Web service in android. I got the output but i dont know that how to store that result in Array..My code is look like

```
SoapObject request=new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("UId","212");
    request.addProperty("verificationID","123456");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Request : "+request.getProperty(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_URL);
    Log.v("Done", request.toString());
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Detail : "+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("RESPONSE : ", response.toString());
    } catch (SoapFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting entire result in object response but dont know how to store in array...If anybody knows than please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following code.

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();          

    String ret[] = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); ++i) {
            ret[i] = response.getProperty(i).toString();
        }
```

Comment: Lots of thanx bro...You solved my problem..one more issue i am facing...Actually my WS returns two result i.e. ID,Name so can i store into different array by this code...??

Comment: Id and Name are combined like " 1 | Name " ?? or they are separate??

Comment: returning like this:         **anytype{id=5; name=akhil; }**

Comment: you can do simple json parsing for this.

Comment: look into this simple tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: first try and learn simple json parsing after then try with your result.

Answer (score 1):

```
List< SoapObject > results = ArrayList< SoapObject >();
... //your code here
results.add(response);
```

List is store objects like array by link.